# windows phone 8 : images in usercontrol : strange behavior

Tags: image, user-controls, windows-phone-8

I have made a usercontrol which consist of many images. but the images don't show up.

if I navigate to some other pages which contains images directly in xaml(all images share the same png as source), then I navigate back and the images in the usercontrol show up.

why? something about caching ?

Thanks.

```
public partial class PatternView : UserControl
{
    List<List<Cube>> pattern;
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Image>> image;
    public PatternView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Init(int row, int col)
    {
        LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
        List<List<Cube>> a=new List<List<Cube>> ();
        ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Image>> b = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Image>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            a.Add(new List<Cube>());
            b.Add(new ObservableCollection<Image>());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            LayoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                a[i].Add(new StoneCube());
                Image img = new Image() 
                { Source = a[i][j].icon };

                img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/CubeImage/Stone.png", UriKind.Relative));
                b[i].Add(img);

                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
                Grid.SetRow(img, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(img, j);
            }
        }
        pattern = a;
        image = b;
    }
```

all elements in "image" don't show up. However, if I go to another page which simply display an Image of the same resource, then come back , everything is fine .

```
public class Cube
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int type;
    public BitmapImage icon { get; protected set; }
    protected int rowSpan;
    protected int colSpan;

    public Cube() 
    {
        name = "basic Cube";
    }
    public Cube(int type)
    {
        name = "basic Cube";
        this.type = type;
    }
}
public class NullCube : Cube
{
    public NullCube() : base()
    {
        name = "null";
        icon = ProgramData.CubeImages["Null"];
    }
}
public class UsedCube : Cube
{
    public UsedCube() : base()
    {
        name = "used";
        icon = ProgramData.CubeImages["Null"];
    }
}
public class StoneCube : Cube
{
    public StoneCube() : base()
    {
        name = "stone";
        icon = ProgramData.CubeImages["Stone"];
    }
}
public class AmmoCube : Cube
{
    public AmmoCube() : base()
    {
        name = "ammo";
        icon = ProgramData.CubeImages["Ammo"];
    }
}

static class ProgramData
{
    public static Dictionary<string,BitmapImage> CubeImages = new Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Cube> ChooseCubeBar { get; set; }


    static ProgramData()
    {
        CubeImages.Add("Stone", new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/CubeImage/Stone.png", UriKind.Relative)));
        CubeImages.Add("Null", new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/CubeImage/Null.png", UriKind.Relative)));
        CubeImages.Add("Ammo", new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/CubeImage/Ammo.png", UriKind.Relative)));
        CubeImages.Add("Cannon", new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/CubeImage/Cannon.png", UriKind.Relative)));
    }
```

Comment: Could you offer a code sample?

Comment: What do you mean "a usercontrol which consists of many images"? Post some code which shows which controls are not displaying the images correctly and how they get initialized/created/bound.

Comment: If I change BitmapCreateOption to BitmapCreateOption.None, solved , but will this influence performance?